# count currentrow of cfoutput inside cfoutput

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

here is the situation, i have a table that displays some values, moreover there are one cfoutput inside the other, thus the currentrows are counted separately, anyway, i hope everything will be clear after source:

```
<cfquery name="get_products" datasource="#dsn3#">
    SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,PR.PRICE,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,P.BARCOD
    FROM PRODUCT P
        JOIN PRICE_STANDART PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID
        JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
        JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.GET_STOCK_LAST GSL ON P.PRODUCT_ID = GSL.PRODUCT_ID
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.is_stock') and attributes.is_stock is 1>
            AND GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK > 0
        </cfif>
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.product_catid') and len(attributes.product_catid)>
            JOIN PRODUCT_CAT PC ON P.PRODUCT_CATID = PC.PRODUCT_CATID
        </cfif>
    WHERE PS.PURCHASESALES=1 AND PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1 AND P.IS_SALES=1 AND P.IS_PURCHASE=1 AND P.IS_INTERNET=1 AND P.IS_EXTRANET=1
    AND PR.STARTDATE <= #now()# AND (PR.FINISHDATE >= #now()# OR PR.FINISHDATE IS NULL)

    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID,PR.PRICE,P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,P.BARCOD
    P.PRODUCT_ID, PR.PRICE DESC
</cfquery>
```

then table:

```
<cfoutput query="get_products" startrow="#attributes.startrow#" maxrows="#attributes.maxrows#" group="product_id">
        <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row"> 
            <td>
                <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=product.form_upd_product&pid=#product_id#" style="color:blue;" target="_blank">#left(product_name,50)#</a>
            </td>
            <td>#left(PRODUCT_DETAIL2,50)#</td>
            <td align="center"><cfif len(brand_list)>#get_brands.brand_name[listfind(brand_list,brand_id,',')]#</cfif></td>
            <td align="center">#PRODUCT_STOCK#</td>
            <td align="center">#saleable_stock#</td>
            <td align="center">#purchase_order_stock#</td>
            <cfoutput><td align="center">#tlformat(price,2)# <cfif currentrow eq 4>asd</cfif></td></cfoutput>
            <td align="center"><a href="javascript://" onclick="gizle_goster(abr#currentrow#);" style="font-weight:bold;">x #saleable_stock#</a></td>
            <td align="center">#MONEY#</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row" id="abr#currentrow#" style="display:none;">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">#saleable_stock# x</td>
            <cfoutput>
                <td align="center" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">#tlformat((saleable_stock*price),2)#</td>
                <cfset abr = tlformat((saleable_stock*price),2)>
            </cfoutput>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">#MONEY#</td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
```

and the result:
http://s008.radikal.ru/i303/1110/2a/031496096958.png

as you can see writing "asd" is only displayed in the first row of the outside cfoutput, but in the 4th row of the inside cfoutput. ( there are 4 prices in one row )
All i want is to write the "asd" in every row of the outside cfoutput, and in the 4th row of the inside row.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Do not forget to `ORDER BY Product_id, ...` first to ensure the grouping always works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a grouped output, the CURRENTROW var of a CFQUERY doesn't behave like you would think.

The quickest solution would be to set and increment a new variable within your grouped output, here:

```
<cfset iter = 1 />
<cfoutput><td align="center">#tlformat(price,2)# <cfif iter eq 4>asd</cfif></td><cfset iter++ /></cfoutput>
```

Be sure to reset the var at the start of any new grouped output (so duplicate this code in your second `<TR>` row as well).

Comment: Thank you Shawn! that's exactly what i wanted! ^.^